# Why is a generic implementing an interface not covariant, but a generic of a base class is?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, covariance

I noticed while trying to implement a generic that there was different behavior between a class with a generic that implements an interface vs a class with a generic that extends a Base class. With the interface, I can't call a function that takes an Enumerable of the interface type, but with the class everything works just fine. Here's an example

```cs
public interface IBarInterface
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooInterface<TInterface> where TInterface : IBarInterface
{
    private List<TInterface> _items;

    public List<TInterface> Items => _items;

    // Does not compile:
    //  Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TInterface>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IBarInterface>'
    public bool SomeValue => Processors.DoSomethingInterface(_items);

    public FooInterface()
    {
        _items = new List<TInterface>();
    }
}

public class BarClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooClass<TClass> where TClass : BarClass
{
    private List<TClass> _items;

    public List<TClass> Items => _items;

    // Does compile
    public bool SomeValue => Processors.DoSomethingClass(_items);

    public FooClass()
    {
        _items = new List<TClass>();
    }
}

public static class Processors
{
    public static bool DoSomethingInterface(IEnumerable<IBarInterface> items)
        => items.Count() % 2 == 0;

    public static bool DoSomethingClass(IEnumerable<BarClass> items)
        => items.Count() % 2 == 0;
}
```

`FooInterface` fails to compile, but `FooBar` compiles just fine. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crucial difference between interfaces and classes in this case, is that *structs* can implement interfaces too! Covariance/contravariance conversions, like converting from `IEnumerable<Subtype>` to `IEnumerable<Supertype>`, is only available if `Subtype` and `Supertype` are both reference types.

In the case of `FooClass<TClass>`, `TClass` is constrained to be a subclass of `BarClass`, so `TClass` has to be a reference type.

In the case of `FooInterface<TInterface>`, `TInterface` is only constrained to be an implementation of `IBarInterface`, so it can be `struct` too. There is no guarantee that a covariance conversion is valid at `DoSomethingInterface(_items)`.

So if you just ensure that `TInterface` cannot be a value type,

```
where TInterface : class, IBarInterface
```

then the error will be gone.